# Django MPTT how to remove indentation from html template

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I am using django MPTT model in my template and just want to remove indentation. Now it's look like this:

[image]

how to remove indentation from html template?

here is my html:

```
 {% load mptt_tags %}
                            
 {%  recursetree contact %}


       {{node.message}}


      {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
      <div class="children pl-2 pl-md-5">
      {{ children }}

     
{% endif %}
{% endrecursetree %}
```